# How do I change the default MySQL user on OpenSuSE 13.1

Tags: mysql, bash, opensuse, mageia

How do I get the "mysql" command to open a connection to MySQL with the root user? I don't want to type mysql --user root, I want it to start immediately.

I have two machines: Mageia 3 and OpenSuSE 13.1. The Mageia machine does this exactly when I open a terminal as the normal user: it simply starts a mysql session and when I type SELECT USER(); it says "root@localhost".

The OpenSuSE machine tries to use the current bash user to connect to mysql instead of using root. How do I configure this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although symcbean's solution works, I found it easier to create a user with the same name as the Linux account that is calling the command. Give this user enough privileges and voilà. This way avoids the problem mentioned by symcbean.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a user option in the [client] section of ~/.my.cnf

...but generally its considered bad practice to use the admin account for normal use of a system.